# Write phones from the contact in the same LinqToXml query?

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have this code.

```
   Dim contact1 As XElement = _
        <contacts>
            <contact>
                <%= From contact In contacts _
                    Select <name><%= contact.Nom %></name> %>
            </contact>
        </contacts>
```

This code actually select contact

There is 2 objects, contact and phone. The contact can hold a list of phone numbers. Here the class details...

```
Public Class Contact

    Private m_Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Phones As List(Of Phone)
    Public Property Phones() As List(Of Phone)
        Get
            Return m_Phones
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Phone))
            m_Phones = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class Phone

    Private m_Contact As Contact
    Public Property Contact() As Contact
        Get
            Return m_Contact
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Contact)
            m_Contact = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Number As String
    Public Property Number() As String
        Get
            Return m_Number
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Number = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

How do i include phones in this query between `<phone type="...">...</phone>` for each of them ?

Bonus (+1) : How to include the type also ?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to post the class definitions of the objects you have and some sample data. Currently it is not clear what kind of data you have and what kind of result you want.

Comment: I added class definition.. however about data.. that can be any kind of data based on these definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't clearly described what result you want or what the problem is, perhaps the following code sample helps:

```
Dim contact1 As New Contact() With {
    .Name = "John Doe",
    .Phones = New List(Of Phone) From {New Phone() With {.Number = "555 12345"}, New Phone() With {.Number = "123 54321"}}
}
Dim contacts As New List(Of Contact)() From {contact1}
Dim contactElements As XElement = _
     <contacts>
         <%= From contact In contacts
             Select <contact>
                        <name><%= contact.Name %></name>
                        <phones>
                            <%= From phone In contact.Phones
                                Select <phone><%= phone.Number %></phone>
                            %>
                        </phones>
                    </contact>
         %>
     </contacts>
```

The output is

```
<contacts>
  <contact>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <phones>
      <phone>555 12345</phone>
      <phone>123 54321</phone>
    </phones>
  </contact>
</contacts>
```

Comment: I though i was pretty clear sorry for confusion. The result are exactly what you wrote i didn't need some special results otherwise i would have said it hehe. Your code is exactly what i needed. Thanks.